# Conda command not working on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda on macOS. It installed successfully, but when I ran the command in terminal it does not recognize the command `conda`. On my initial search, I found out I have look if the environment variable is set in `.bash_profile`. As the following picture shows the path is all set, but I can not still run the command.
[image]

Comment: Please do not post command line/terminal output in images. Please see here for the reasons: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using `bash` but `zsh` as your current shell.
`zsh` does not source `.bash_profile` - instead, it sources the `.zprofile` file for its initialization.

So, just copy the `export PATH=...` line to the `.zprofile` file (create it if it does not exist). Logout and login, and it should work.

Comment: +1 But note that as of conda >= 4.4, the recommended way of adding the conda executable to the `PATH` has changed. See: https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20 the command is `source /path/to/conda/dir/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` then `conda activate base`

Comment: ugh why don't they just provide a conda prompt for mac like they do in windows where it just works