# How to use the correct shell in my Mac terminal?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I just got my Mac back from Apple with a complete reset. I tried downloading and using Anaconda like I normally wood but nothing seemed to be working correctly, so I tried to install Python3 to use because Mac only ships with 2.7

I notice that my terminal has ~% at the end of it, when it used to have ~$ (is this indicative of anything?)

If I try to download python3 and install it from Python.org, it works but then anything I try and do says my Bash doesn't work, or commands aren't recognized.

Comment: What do you mean by "my Bash doesn't work"?

Comment: If they've put the latest OS on, you probably have macOS 10.15.3 Catalina. The default shell in Catalina is zsh, not bash, that's why you're getting the `%` instead of the familiar `$` - nothing to do with Python. (see https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/ for example)

Comment: When you say you tried downloading Anaconda but nothing seemed to be working correctly, can you be rather more specific as to what you mean? I have the latest Anaconda distribution of Python running on Catalina with zsh so it's not an obvious incompatability problem.

Comment: @DavidBuck Thanks for clearing up the % vs $ confusion! I changed my default shell back to bash, and re-installed Anaconda and everything was working. Essentially when zsh was my default and I installed Anaconda, if I tried to do anything as simple as "Conda activate" or "Conda install" I would get error messages as to the syntax and that "command doesn't exist". 
Did you have to do anything different when you downloaded / Installed Anaconda to make it work with zsh?

Comment: Ah. I did have Anaconda installed before upgrading from Mojave to Catalina and switching to zsh, but it had no issues afterwards. Perhaps try a `conda update --all` in each venv and switch back to zsh?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a PATH problem.  When you type conda or Anaconda it doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda command not working on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338768/conda-command-not-working-on-macos)

Comment: Ah, actually this one is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615322/zsh-conda-pip-installs-command-not-found

Comment: @AMC, and JMH, yes you guys are correct on those. figured out the problem. Two solutions works: (1) changing my default shell from zsh to bash and then doing a normal Anaconda install; or (2) changing my path.

Answer (score 0):

Mac does come with a builtin Python2.7 but since that is outdated now, you can install python3 and above using hombrew python, just follow the steps within this link. If it still doesn't work, you may need to reconfigure your initial path settings.

See [link](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/).